# How to change audio bitrate to exactly 85 Kbps and preserve video setting?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, video-encoding, quicktime, bitrate

When I try to change the audio bitrate for my video, also my video output is lower than it should be. Also my output video should be in MOV format.

I tried:

```
./ffmpeg -i myvideo.mov.mp4 -b:a 85k output.mov
```

Comment: what codecs do you want to use? x264 for video, aac for audio? and what is the goal? to make a file compatible for web-streaming, or just make any file to be playable with e.g. VLC?

Comment: I would like to use h264 for video and mp4a for audio

Comment: try something along:
`ffmpeg -i myvideo.mov.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -c:a aac -b:a 85k output.mov`
the `-crf`-flag specifies the constant rate factor - you could call it a "preset for quality". `0` means lossless, `20` usually means "no visible quality-loss". [link to ffmpeg's h264-guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264)

if your input-file already has h264 as a video-codec, then you could also use `-c:v copy` to just copy the video-stream into the new file.

Comment: I tried the mentioned code but still the video bitrate is lower than my origninal, I'll tried the -c:v copy an it worked. Where can I give you the up vote?

Comment: the same (or higher) bitrate doesn't necessarily mean that the quality is higher (or even the same)
e.g. you take your video-file, encode it with `-b:v 1k`. then you take the resulting file and specify `-crf 0`, meaning lossless. the file-size will increase significantly, but the quality will stay at the same low niveau as the first file.

so if `-crf 20` gives you a file that is visually indistinguishable from the original, but the bitrate dropped, then it only means that the encoder works more efficiently than the original one.

as for voting: there is an arrow to the left of a comment.